# Set focus in input box using on click - Angular js

Tags: angularjs

Hello I am trying ng_focus on click button like

**Input Box Code:**

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="" class="promocode"    ng-focus="focus"  ng-model="text"  value="" />
```

**Button Code:**

```
<span ng-click="text = 'sheetesh'; focus=true"> Sheetesh </span>
<p>focus: {{focus}}</p>
```

And Its return true click on span but focus is not work.

focus: true

Screen Shot:
     [its showing like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5EFY.png)

Comment: `ng-focus` is not for setting focus. It's like `ng-click`. Value of `ng-focus` will be executed when focus event occurs.

Answer (score 3):

## document.getElementById

Try this:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="" class="promocode" ng-model="text" value="" />

<span ng-click="text = 'sheetesh'; document.getElementById('myInput').focus();"> Sheetesh </span>
```

## angular.element

Alternative version with angular.element:

```
<span ng-click="text = 'sheetesh'; angular.element('#myInput').focus();"> Sheetesh </span>
```

Comment: I have already use it but its not working.


       <input type="text" class="promocode" id ="promocodea"    ng-model="text"  value="" />

       <span ng-click="text = 'sheetesh'; angular.element('#promocodea').focus();" class="fcs32">sheetesh</span>

Comment: @RITU are there any errors in console? Did you try the first solution?

Comment: yeah i tried Not showing any error in console but not working .

Answer (score 0):

you not need to set focus. just add 'tabindex' attribute to element
then automatically focus will go on element on

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="" class="promocode" ng-model="text" value="" />

<span ng-click="text = 'sheetesh';" tabindex="0"> Sheetesh </span>
```

onclick